# Postgres terminology: client vs connection

Tags: postgresql

In Postgres, is there a one-to-one relationship between a client and a connection? In other word, is a client always one connection and no client can open more than one connection?

For example, when Postgres says:

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: sorry, too many clients already.

is that equivalent to "too many connections already"?

Also, as far as I understand, Postgres uses one process for each client. So does this mean that each process is used for one connection only?

Answer (score 1):

Refer - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/connect-estab.html

> PostgreSQL is implemented using a simple "process per user"
>   client/server model. In this model there is one client process
>   connected to exactly one server process. As we do not know ahead of
>   time how many connections will be made, we have to use a master
>   process that spawns a new server process every time a connection is
>   requested.

So yes, one server process serves one connection.

Comment: I understand that one server process serves one client. What I want to know is whether one client can have multiple connections all connecting to the same server process or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can have as many connections from a single client (machine, application) as the server can manage. The server can support a given number of connections, whether or not these come from different clients (machine, application) is irrelevant to the server.

The connection is made to the `postmaster` process that is listening on the port that PG is configured to listen to (5432 by default). When a connection is established (after authentication), the server spawns a process which is used exclusively by a single client. That client can make multiple connections to the same server, for instance to connect to different databases, or the same database using different credentials, etc.